# Maven cxf-codegen-plugin and import in wsdl

Tags: java, apache, maven, wsdl, cxf

I'm trying to generate webservice classes from wsdl file using apache **cxf-codegen-plugin** from maven.
My wsdl file imports xsd like below using

```xml
<xs:import namespace="http://my.ns.com/privateperson" schemaLocation="../xsd/PrivatePerson.xsd"/>
```

and in pom.xml I have:

```xml
<wsdlOption>
    <extraargs>
       <extraarg>-catalog ${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/PrivatePerson.xsd</extraarg>
       <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
    </extraargs>
    ...
</wsdlOptions>
```

However when I run cxf-codegen-plugin I get the following error:

```
wsdl2java failed: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.parser.BadUsageException: Unexpected option: -catalog valid/path/to/xsd/file/privateperson.xsd
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration? When I don't include external xsd file everything works fine.

I used catalog as it is described here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

I have also run maven with -e:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.0-milestone1:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project Services: unresolved reference -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.0-milestone1:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project Services: unresolved reference
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: unresolved reference
at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:447)
at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:311)
at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:524)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: unresolved reference
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef._get(DelayedRef.java:103)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef$Type.getType(DelayedRef.java:148)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.ElementDecl.getType(ElementDecl.java:110)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.ElementDecl.updateSubstitutabilityMap(ElementDecl.java:174)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.getResult(ParserContext.java:141)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.getResult(XSOMParser.java:211)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:538)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:269)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:460)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:714)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:270)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:427)
... 29 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved my issue - in wsdl I have placed

```
<xs:import ... />
```

in wrong place. It was before

```
<wsdl:types>
```

element.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the extra arguments must be on its own; you tried to pass two in one, and that won't work because of the care the plugin takes to quote things correctly for you (or to pass each argument as a separate element of the argument array, depending on whether it execs under the covers or not).

You want this:

```xml
<wsdlOption>
    <extraargs>
        <extraarg>-catalog</extraarg>
        <extraarg>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/PrivatePerson.xsd</extraarg>
        <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
    </extraargs>
    ...
</wsdlOptions>
```

(Be aware that getting catalogs right can take experimentation; the logging of failures in XML catalog lookups is… virtually non-existent.)

Comment: I've tried it, but it didn't help. The error message is the same. I've also put xsd file into the same directory, where PrivatePersonService.wsdl is.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following tag and check if it works

```
 <wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>${basedir}/<file-path></wsdl>
    </wsdlOption>
    </wsdlOptions>
```

also check which version of cxf plugin you are using. Try to use the latest one.

Let me know if its still giving error

Comment: The version, which I'm using is 3.0.0-milestone1.

Comment: I think you missed to add the lifecycle configuration for generate-sources..<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.5</version>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <id>generate-sources</id>
     <phase>generate-sources</phase>
     <configuration>
      <wsdlOptions>
       <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/.....</wsdl>
       </wsdlOption>
      </wsdlOptions>
     </configuration>
     <goals>
      <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
     </goals>
    </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>.. add the following plugin